# SSRS web service Render method takes longer from code compared to manually hitting View Report from the URL

Tags: sql-server, performance, web-services, reporting-services

Has anyone used the **Render** method from the SSRS Web Service **ReportExecution2005**?

I noticed that generating the report from the code is taking longer than when the report is manually generated using the URL. Is there something I can configure/setup?

Here's the code I used:

The code is working it's just that the performance is noticeably slow and for some reports it's taking forever compared to when it's run manually just takes < 5 seconds.

```
        public byte[] GetSSRSInvoice(string invoiceNumber)
        {
            byte[] reportBytes = null;
            using (var webServiceProxy = new SSRSWebReference.ReportExecutionService())

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSReportPath")) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSUserDomain")) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSUserName")) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSUserPassword")))
            {
                string sUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSUserName");
                string sUserDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSUserDomain");
                string sUserPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSUserPassword");
                string reportName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSRSReportPath");
                webServiceProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUserName, sUserPassword, sUserDomain);

                // Init Report to execute
                ExecutionInfo executionInfo = webServiceProxy.LoadReport(reportName, null);

                ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[3];
                parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[0].Name = "GENERIC";
                parameters[0].Value = invoiceNumber;
                parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[1].Name = "TYPE";
                parameters[1].Value = "1";
                parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[2].Name = "PARAMTYPE";
                parameters[2].Value = "1";   

                // Attach Report Parameters
                webServiceProxy.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, null);
                string extension, mimeType, encoding;
                Warning[] warnings;
                string[] streamIds;

                // Render
                reportBytes = webServiceProxy.Render(ExportFormat.PDF.ToString(), null, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds);

            }
            return reportBytes;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly how I do it without any performance issues. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201639/ssrs-report-very-slow-in-prod-but-sql-query-runs-fast) is similar and has good links in the answers which may help you.

Comment: thanks @ChrisLätta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the report for view purpose from the URL, it executed in RPL render format. During this step, your report takes time for
1.  Data fetch
2.  And rendering

So total time taken is (Data fetch time + rendering time). Now you export the same report into other format (like PDF/XLS etc), then total time would be as is (Data fetch time during RPL render + rendering time during RPL render+ rendering time for selected export format/render). Note that depend on selected export format, render time will vary.

Now if we talk about your code using ReportExecution2005, you are exporting your report into PDF format. In this case total time would be as (Data Fetch time + Render/export to PDF time +C# Code Execution time). 
Based on this, you would be able to compare fair times between two different render for the same report.